# Scanner with unknown lines of input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have issue letting my program know when I'm done supplying input using Scanner. The following code works for a single paragraph after I supply the input and press enter twice in my IDE terminal.

```
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            ArrayList<String> als = new ArrayList<>();
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                String s = scanner.nextLine();
                if(s.equals("")) break; 
                als.add(s);
            }
            scanner.close();
            for(String ss : als) System.out.println(ss);
```

I would however like to supply multiple paragraphs of input ie.

```
word word word word
word word word word

word word word word
word word word word
```

and store them all in the arraylist then print it.

Comment: So how would the program know when to stop reading?

Comment: I suppose when there are only empty lines coming through. Is there a way to make it stop after two lines of ""?

Comment: A more "correct" way of doing it would be having a sequence of characters indicating EOF (e.g. ENDOFFILE) so when the Scanner reads it, it stops. You can also do a `while (scanner.hasNext())` loop so that when you enter EOF (ctrl+c) the input stop automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suppose when there are only empty lines coming through. Is there a way to make it stop after two lines of ""?

In that case, you can add a `boolean` variable that indicates whether the last line is empty:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> als = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean lastLineIsEmpty = false;
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        String s = scanner.nextLine();
        if(s.equals("")) { // this line is empty
            if (lastLineIsEmpty) { // last line is also empty
                break;
            } else { // last line is not empty, set the variable to true
                lastLineIsEmpty = true;
            }
        } else { // this line is not empty, reset the variable
            lastLineIsEmpty = false;
        }
        als.add(s);
    }
    for(String ss : als) System.out.println(ss);
```

If you want it to stop after *N* lines of `""`, you can instead use an `int` variable, that counts how many consecutive empty lines the scanner has seen.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64120669/scanner-with-unknown-lines-of-input#comment113387461_64120669) to your question:

> Is there a way to make it stop after two lines of ""?

Just add a counter that counts the number of consecutive blank lines entered. Once the counter is greater than one, you have reached the end of the input.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Paragraf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<String> als = new ArrayList<>();
        int count = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = scanner.nextLine();
            if (s.isEmpty()) {
                count++;
                if (count > 1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else {
                count = 0;
            }
            als.add(s);
        }
        als.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

By the way, you should not close a `Scanner` that wraps `System.in`.